# Local module not found with PyCall in ruby on rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pycall

I'm trying to call a python function in a file in my ruby on rails application.

My python file is located at `project_dir/lib/assets/python/the_file.py`
I'm utilizing PyCall for ruby with the lines:

```
require 'pycall'
PyCall.sys.path.append('/lib/assets/python')
file_import = PyCall.import_module("the_file")
```

I get an error saying
`<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>: No module named 'the_file'`

Is it just a syntax error?
Is there a better different way I should be trying to run my python script in rails?

I am using ruby 3.0.0, rails 7.0.2, and python 3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative path:

```rb
PyCall.sys.path.append('./lib/assets/python')
```